# Return Count() days to expire days

Tags: c#, linq

I want to return count() the Items where alert days to expire is less than or equal to (ExpireDate - Datetime.Now), I am using linq to sql in c#.
I get this error:

> Method 'Int32 getDifference(System.DateTime)' has no supported translation to SQL.

Any help will be appreciated.
Here is my code:

```
public static int getAlertDays()
{
   using (var db = new AWarehouseDataClassesDataContext())
   {
     var count = (from i in db.tblItems
                 where (getDifference(i.ExpireDate) <= i.AlertDays)
                 select i).Count();
     return count;
   }
}

private static int getDifference(DateTime expireDate)
{
   return (expireDate - DateTime.Now).Days;
}
```

Comment: Just replace the call to `getDifference` with the that line of code in your Linq.  The problem is that it's trying to convert that to SQL and doesn't know how to translate your method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is stating that your method `getDifference` is not supported in SQL i.e. there is no method in SQL that has that name. I believe all you need to do is inline that function into the statement for it to work i.e.

```
var count = (from i in db.tblItems
             where ((i.ExpireDate - DateTime.Now).Days <= i.AlertDays)
             select i).Count();
```

Answer (score 2):

`System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) has a `DiffDays` function:

```
// Add this to your using
using System.Data.Entity;

// Back to your example
var count = db.tblItems.Count(i =>
                DbFunctions.DiffDays(i.ExpireDate, DateTime.Now) <= i.AlertDays);
```

Note that I also changed to using the version of `Count` that takes a lambda, I find it more readable than trying to use `Where` (or equivalently `where`)

Comment: I get this error: The name 'DbFunctions' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @PlazzaSele: You need to add the namespace to your using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DbFunctions.DiffDays`:

```
var count = (from i in db.tblItems
             where DbFunctions.DiffDays(i.ExpireDate, DateTime.Now) <= i.AlertDays
             select i).Count();

             return count;
```